# Proof of Newton's Binomial Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, numerical-methods

I have two issues with my proof, which I will present below. Recall Newton's Binomial Theorem: 
$$(1+x)^t=1+\binom{t}{1}x+\cdot\cdot\cdot=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{t}{k} x^k$$
By cleverly letting $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{t}{k} x^k,$$
we have 
$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \binom{t}{k} k x^{k-1}$$

Claim: $(1+x)f'(x)=tf(x)$

First problem: I would have not been able to come up with this relation had I not assumed that $f(x)=(1+x)^t$

Proof of Claim: Compare coefficients of $x^j$
For the left hand side $(1+x)f'(x)$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\binom{t}{j+1}(1+j)+\binom{t}{j}j=&j\left(\binom{t}{j}+\binom{t}{j+1}\right)+\binom{t}{j+1}\\
=&j\binom{t+1}{j+1}+\binom{t}{j+1}\\
=&\dfrac{t!t(j+1)}{(t-j)!(j+1)!}=\dfrac{t\cdot t!}{(t-j)!j!}\\
=&t\binom{t}{j}
\end{align*}
where the second inequality follows from Pascal's Triangle.
For the right hand side $tf(x)$, we have $t\binom{t}{j}$.

Second Problem: I am not quite sure if comparing coefficients is rigorous enough when proving these theorems. If I show that the degrees of the two polynomials are equal, would that be sufficient?

Comment: Ah, you are taking the infinite expansion to allow for non-integer exponents?  And you are taking derivatives at the same time?  If these are the case, you would prefer to use [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series), which is... the recommended way to go.  Secondly, look at $f'(x)$.  Can you expand the binomial coefficient and simplify?  ;)

Comment: Comparing coefficients is sufficient here, once we have some things down (like the sum converges and some other things).  And would you like me to write down the Taylor expansion method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the issue is to prove the given identity for $t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{N}$, otherwise induction is enough.
By definition of real exponentiation, for any $|x|<1$ we have 
$$(1+x)^t = \exp\left(t\log(1+x)\right) = \exp\left(t\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}x^k\right) \tag{1}$$
hence the LHS is an analytic function in a neighbourhood of $x=0$, and
$$ (1+x)^t = 1+\sum_{m\geq 1}c_m x^m\tag{2} $$
where
$$ c_m = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(1+e^{i\theta})^t e^{-mi\theta}\,d\theta \tag{3} $$
by Cauchy's integral formula, but also
$$\begin{eqnarray*} c_m &=& [x^m] \left(e^{tx}\cdot e^{-tx^2/2}\cdot e^{tx^3/3}\cdots e^{(-1)^{m-1}x^m/m}\right)\\&=&(-1)^m [x^m] \left(e^{-tx}\cdot e^{-tx^2/2}\cdot e^{-tx^3/3}\cdots e^{-tx^m/m}\right)\end{eqnarray*}\tag{4} $$
due to $(1)$. It follows that
$$ c_m = \sum_{a_1+2a_2+\ldots+ma_m=m}\frac{(-t)^{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_m}}{a_1! 2^{a_2}a_2! \cdots m^{a_m}a_m!} \tag{5} $$
and now I leave to you to understand the relation between $\binom{t}{k}$ and the RHS of $(5)$.
It may be useful to recall a few facts about [exponential generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).

---

A simpler approach is to notice that both $f(x)=(1+x)^t$ and $g(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0}\binom{t}{k}x^k$ are solutions of the differential equation
$$(1+x)\cdot h'(x) = t\cdot h(x) $$
such that $h(0)=1$. $f\equiv g$ hence follows from the Cauchy-Lipschitz theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The  combinatorial  proof  starts  from the  unique  factorization  of
permutations into disjoint cycles which gives the species

$$\mathfrak{P}(\mathcal{U}\mathfrak{C}(\mathcal{Z}))$$

with bivariate EGF $$G(z, u) = \exp\left(u\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)$$

which yields the Stirling numbers of the first kind

$$\left[n\atop k\right]
= n! [z^n] \frac{1}{k!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^k.$$

We thus have

$$n! [z^n] G(z, u) 
= \sum_{k=1}^n \left[n\atop k\right] u^k.$$

Therefore

$$n! [z^n] G(z, u) = n! (-1)^n [z^n] G(-z, u) =
u(u+1)(u+2)\cdots(u+n-1).$$

Hence

$$n! (-1)^n [z^n] G(-z, -u) = (-1)^n u(u-1)(u-2)\cdots(u-(n-1))$$

and finally

$$n! [z^n] \exp\left(-u\log\frac{1}{1+z}\right)
\\ = n! [z^n] \exp(u\log(1+z)) = u(u-1)(u-2)\cdots(u-(n-1))$$

so that

$$[z^n] \exp(u\log(1+z)) = 
\frac{1}{n!} u(u-1)(u-2)\cdots(u-(n-1))
= {u\choose n}.$$